# How are U/V Values Calculated in RGB to NV21 (YUV420SP) Conversion?

Tags: java, android, opencv

thanks for reading:

I am writing an OpenCV application for Android which involves image stabilization. The image stabilization involves tracking features from frame to frame, calculating a homography matrix from the LK optical flow, then applying the transform to stabilize the image. The preview image I process comes in as NV21/YUV420SP (Can't change this to RGB) and I convert it to RGB using OpenCV's CvtColor function as so:

```
Mat yuvFrame = new Mat((int)(params.getPreviewSize().height * 1.5), params.getPreviewSize().width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
yuvFrame.put(0, 0, data);
Mat rgbFrame = new Mat(params.getPreviewSize().height, params.getPreviewSize().width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
Imgproc.cvtColor(yuvFrame, rgbFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21);
```

After this conversion, I process the image to stabilize it. But my problem is converting the RGB frame back to NV21 (I can't avoid this). I don't know how to calculate the U/V values since they depend on a window of RGB values and I don't know which RGB values to use to generate the U/V values.

The YUV format for an image frame says there are single U/V coordinates per four pixels of Y data [as seen in this image.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Yuv420.svg/1920px-Yuv420.svg.png)

It makes sense why NV21 images are single-channel but 1.5 times the height of their grayscale counterparts. The Y channel is essentially the gray channel because it describes brightness. Calculating the Y values is easy because there is one for every pixel on the screen. But the U/V channels have 1/4 the number of values of the Y channel. Below is the for loop to calculate the Y values from an RGB Mat.

```
    private byte[] rgb2nv21(Mat rgbFrame) {

        byte[] y = new byte[rgb.rows + rgb.cols];
        byte[] u = new byte[((int)(rgb.rows * 0.25)) * ((int)rgb.cols)];
        byte[] v = new byte[((int)(rgb.rows * 0.25)) * ((int)rgb.cols)];
        int index = 0;
        // Loop through Mat to convert RGB to YUV
        for (int i = 0; i < rgbFrame.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rgbFrame.cols; j++) {
                // Cast as floats to avoid overflow in byte values
                float r = rgbFrame.get(i, j, 0)/255.0
                float g = rgbFrame.get(i, j, 1)/255.0
                float b = rgbFrame.get(i, j, 2)/255.0
                y[index] = (byte)(((0.257 * r) + (0.504 * g) + (0.098 * b) + 16) * 255.0);
                index++;
            }
        }

        // Create single byte stream to represent frame
        byte[] yuvStream = new byte[y.length + u.length + v.length];
        return yuvStream;
    }
```

The formulas for U/V values from RGB values are:

```
u = (-(0.148 * r) - (0.291 * g) + (0.439 * b) + 128;
v = (0.439 * r) - (0.368 * g) - (0.071 * b) + 128;
```

But in NV21, the U/V values are representative of a 2x2 window and 4 Y pixels. Which RGB values from the RGB frame should be used to generate the U/V values? Do I use the average of the color channel's corresponding window to generate the U/V coordinates? Like this?

```
r_window = (r1 + r2 + r7 + r8)/4;
g_window = (g1 + g2 + g7 + g8)/4;
b_window = (b1 + b2 + b7 + b8)/4;

u = (-(0.148 * r_window) - (0.291 * g_window) + (0.439 * b_window) + 128;
v = (0.439 * r_window) - (0.368 * g_window) - (0.071 * b_window) + 128;
```

This makes the most sense despite the fact that some information will be lost on conversion. However, before implementing the logic to do this, I need to verify this is the case. On a personal note, I feel this is something fourcc.org should elaborate on. Please help.

Thank you again for reading.